# ViewGroup.setLayerType to Hardware cause blurriness, aliasing issue on child views

Tags: android, blur, zooming, antialiasing, hardware-acceleration

I have complex UI, similar to a 3D chessboard, which can be zoomed/panned.
To accomplish this had a custom ViewGroup. But I encountered performance issues in this like lagging in zooming/Panning, thus after searching for while I found out the solution is to used Hardware layer support. And had to set the layer type of my ViewGroup to "LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE" which indeed solve the performance issue, but lead to another problem of UI quality, i.e: blurriness and aliasing for images and texts inside the ViewGroup.

```
public class ZoomLayout extends FrameLayout implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener, View.OnDragListener {
    float x1=0, y1=0, x2, y2;
    ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;
    OnDragListener onDragListener;
    Context mContext;
    private static final String TAG = "ZoomLayout";
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 6.0f;

    private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
    private float scale = 1.0f;
    private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

    // Where the finger first  touches the screen
    private float startX = 0f;
    private float startY = 0f;

    // How much to translate the canvas
    private float dx = 0f;
    private float dy = 0f;
    private float prevDx = 0f;
    private float prevDy = 0f;

    ApiCommunicationListener apiListener;
    Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

    private enum Mode {
        NONE,
        DRAG,
        ZOOM
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, ApiCommunicationListener apiListener, Activity activity) {
        super(context);
        this.apiListener = apiListener;
        this.mActivity = activity;
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        ApocketApp.areTwoViewsClicked = false;
        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = motionEvent.getX();
                y1 = motionEvent.getY();

                if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
                    mode = Mode.DRAG;
                    startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
                    startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
                    dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
                    dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                mode = Mode.ZOOM;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                x2 = motionEvent.getX();
                y2 = motionEvent.getY();

                mode = Mode.NONE;
                prevDx = dx;
                prevDy = dy;
                if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && ApocketApp.mViewClicked != null) {


                    break;
                }
                scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

                if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
                    dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
                    dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);

                    applyScaleAndTranslation();
                }
        }

            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
            float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();

            if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
                scale *= scaleFactor;
                scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
                lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
            } else {
                lastScaleFactor = 0;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {

        }

    private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
        child().setScaleX(scale);
        child().setScaleY(scale);
        child().setTranslationX(dx);
        child().setTranslationY(dy);
    }

    private View child() {
        return getChildAt(0);
    }

    public void animateToCentre(final RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {

        Resources res  = mContext.getResources();
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        res.getValue(R.dimen.zoom_centre_level_max, outValue, true);
        final float zoomEnd = outValue.getFloat();
        ObjectAnimator oaX = new ObjectAnimator();
        oaX.setDuration(res.getInteger(R.integer.zoom_centre_duration));
        oaX.setFloatValues(new float[]{1.0f, zoomEnd});
        oaX.setPropertyName("scaleX");
        oaX.setFrameDelay(10);
        ObjectAnimator oaY = new ObjectAnimator();
        oaY.setDuration(res.getInteger(R.integer.zoom_centre_duration));
        oaY.setFloatValues(new float[]{1.0f, zoomEnd});
        oaY.setPropertyName("scaleY");
        oaY.setFrameDelay(10);
        ObjectAnimator oaTy = new ObjectAnimator();
        oaTy.setDuration(res.getInteger(R.integer.zoom_centre_duration));
        oaTy.setFloatValues(new float[]{0.0f, res.getDimension(R.dimen.v_5) * 3});
        oaTy.setPropertyName("translationY");
        oaTy.setFrameDelay(10);

        AnimatorSet zoomAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
        zoomAnimation.playTogether(new ObjectAnimator[]{oaX, oaY, oaTy});
        zoomAnimation.setTarget(child());
        zoomAnimation.setInterpolator(new FastOutLinearInInterpolator());
        zoomAnimation.start();
        zoomAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                child().setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                scale = zoomEnd;
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```